# Angle chasing problem with quadrilateral - possible approaches?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof, quadrilateral

**CONTEXT**

I was recently working on some Langley-style problems, and wanted to construct some others, based on the "reverse engineering" approach I developed to solve them.

**PROBLEM**

The quadrilateral $ABCD$ is such that $\measuredangle ABC = 51^\circ$ and $\measuredangle DAB = 135^\circ$. Furthermore, a point $P$ inside the quadrilateral and a point $Q\in BC$ can be found such that

1. $AP \parallel DQ$,
2. $AD \cong AP \cong PQ$,
3. $CD \cong PD \cong PC$.

[image]

What is $\measuredangle BCD$?

**QUESTIONS**

I have a solution, since I myself constructed the problem (should I give it here? Or would this just be some sort of "bias"?). But I am wondering

1. Are there feasible/interesting approaches to solve the problem?
2. Are there even more than one solution to it?

**EDIT**
To avoid any confusion. This is not a test or a homework. I am not even a student. My solution is $\measuredangle BCD= 78^\circ$, but I obtained it from a cumbersome geometric construction, and I am wondering if this can be obtained in some more direct way, and if there are other solutions.

Comment: Yes, you should include your solution, otherwise it's just another "here's the problem, now solve it"-type question lol

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Please do not use expressions such as "lol" in this context. I will post numerical solution and my approach if necessary. Please be polite.

Comment: Is it against the rules?

Comment: Dear @H.sapiensrex it's just a way of not being rude. I did not ask you to solve the problem.

Comment: I was not trying to be rude, nor imply that you wanted us to solve it... I was simply answering your question regarding posting your own solution and pointing out that if you didn't, that that would be the perception of your question... I think you have misunderstood me

Comment: Dear sir @H.sapiensrex I assume that people read what I wrote and can desume that it is true. I'm not a student. It is not a homework or a test. And the reason why I didn't give the solution right away is clearly explained in OP.

Comment: The angle $ABD$ cannot be $135^o$. But the angle $DAB$ can be equal to $135^o$.

Comment: It seems this has more than one solution. For instance, $\measuredangle BCD=69^o$. Can you please check?

Comment: @YNK I'll edit right away, and check ASAP.

Comment: @YNK, thanks for your contribution. I cannot find the construction you mention. If $\measuredangle BCD = 69^\circ$ I obtain a quadrilateral that satisfies 1. and 3. but not 2. In particular $AD \cong AP$, but $PQ \not \cong AP$...